# Is it possible to write shell command within Pharo smalltalk?

Tags: linux, shell, smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

Like in other programming language, is there a way of running linux shell command in Pharo smalltalk or a simple script ? I would like to have my Pharo image running a script that should be able to automate a tasks and return it to some value. I looked at almost all the documentation around and I couldn't find anything related. Maybe It does not allow such functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking shell commands from Squeak or Pharo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416624/invoking-shell-commands-from-squeak-or-pharo)

Comment: @eMBee How is that a duplicate?

Comment: Do you want to **call** a command line tool from within Pharo or **write** a command line tool with Pharo? The first would be a duplicate of [Invoking shell commands from Squeak or Pharo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416624/invoking-shell-commands-from-squeak-or-pharo). Installing `OSProcess` from the Pharo Project Catalog would be a solution for this.

Comment: you are asking to run a shell command and get some return value. the other question asks about invoking a shell command and capturing the output. those are pretty much the same thing. the answer to your question could just as well be an answer to the other question. the only problem with the other question is that none of the answers explain how to capture the output. i am suggesting that your question might be a duplicate. i am not declaring that it is. if your question is any different then please feel free to elaborate.

Comment: as it is, i would suggest the answers of the two questions be merged, and one question be marked duplicate of the other.

Comment: also please clarify if you want to capture the exit status of the command or the output from stdout and/or stderr, or both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pharo does allow the OS interaction.  The best way, in my eyes, is to use `OSProcess` (as [MartinW](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2012262/martinw) already suggested).

Those that think it is a duplicate are missing this part:

> ... running a script that should be able to automate a tasks and
> return it to some value...

There is nothing about return value in the [invoking shell commands from squeak or pharo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416624/invoking-shell-commands-from-squeak-or-pharo)

To get a return value you would do it the following way:

```
command := OSProcess waitForCommand: 'ls -la'.
command exitStatus.
```

If you print out the above code you will get most probably a `0` as success.

If you do an obvious error:

```
command := OSProcess waitForCommand: 'ls -la /dir-does-not-exists'.
command exitStatus.
```

You will get `~= 0` value in my case `512`.

### **Edit** adding more details to cover more ground

I agree with eMBee that a statement

> return it to some value

is rather vague.  I'm adding information about I/Os.

As you may know there are three basic IO:  `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.  These you need to interact with shell.  I'll add these examples first then I'll get back to your description.

Each of them is represented by instance of `AttachableFileStream` in Pharo.  For the above `command` you will get `initialStdIn` (`stdin`), `initialStdOut` (`stdout`), `initialStdError` (`stderr`).

To write **into** the terminal **from** Pharo:

1. *stdout* and *stderr* (you stream string into terminal)

   ```
   | process |

   process := OSProcess thisOSProcess.
   process stdOut nextPutAll: 'stdout: All your base belong to us'; nextPut: Character lf.
   process stdErr nextPutAll: 'stderr: All your base belong to us'; nextPut: Character lf.
   ```

Check your shell you should see the output there.

2. *stdin* - to get what you typed

   ```
   | userInput handle fetchUserInput |

   userInput := OSProcess thisOSProcess stdIn.
   handle := userInput ioHandle.
   "You need this in order to use terminal -> add stdion"
   OSProcess accessor setNonBlocking: handle.
   fetchUserInput := OS2Process thisOSProcess stdIn next.
   "Set blocking back to the handle"
   OSProcess accessor setBlocking: handle.
   "Gets you one input character"
   fetchUserInput inspect.
   ```

If you want to grab an output **from** the command **into** Pharo a resonable way is to use `PipeableOSProcess` which, as apparent from his name,  can be used in conjunction with pipes.

Simple example:

```
| commandOutput |

commandOutput := (PipeableOSProcess command: 'ls -la') output.
commandOutput inspect.
```

More complex example:

```
| commandOutput |

commandOutput := ((PipeableOSProcess command: 'ps -ef') | 'grep pharo') outputAndError.
commandOutput inspect.
```

I like the use of `outputAndError` because of typos.  If you have an incorrect command you will get the error message:

```
| commandOutput |

commandOutput := ((PipeableOSProcess command: 'ps -ef') | 'grep pharo' | 'cot') outputAndError.
commandOutput  inspect.
```

In this case `'/bin/sh: cot: command not found'`

That is about it.

**Update 29-3-2021**  The *OSProcess* works up to Pharo 7.  It was not upgraded to work with the changes at Pharo 8 or newer.

Comment: "There is nothing about return value in the invoking shell commands from squeak or pharo": uhm, the other question does mention "capture the output of commands", so yes, that question does ask for the return value. nevertheless your answer is better than the others.

Comment: btw: neither question is clear on exactly which value they want. whether the exitstatus or the output on stdout or stderr. it would be nice if you could add both to your answer.

Comment: @eMBee Well you are right.  I have added both ways.

Comment: @eMBee hehe, glad you like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer Pharo you do not need dependencies. You can run:

```
LibC uniqueInstance resultOfCommand: 'ls -la'.
```