# How to interact with a subprocess through its stdin, stdout, stderr in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

This Python code shows how to call some process in **Windows 10** and to send to it string commands, to read its string responses through stdin, stdout pipes of the process:

```py
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> p = Popen("c:/python38/python.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write(b"print(1+9)\n")
11
>>> p.communicate()
(b'10\r\n', None)
>>>
```

As you can see the python.exe process returned 10 as an answer to `print(1+9)`. Now I want to do the same in Pharo (or Squeak): in Windows 10 OS - I suppose something similar, i.e. short, simple, understandable, really working.

I installed OSProcess, ProcessWrapper (they were missing in Pharo, also its strange that I got warning that they are not marked for Pharo 8.0 and were not checked to work in Pharo 8.0, but OK), and I tried ProcessWrapper, PipeableOSProcess (copy-pasted different snippets from the Web), etc - with zero success! The results were:

- nothing happens, python.exe was not started
- VM errors console was opened (white console in the bottom of the Pharo, which is controlled with F2 menu)
- different exceptions
- etc

Would somebody show me simple working example how to start a process and to to send it commands, read answers, then send again, and so on in some loop - I plan to have such communication in a detached thread and to use it as some service, because Pharo, Smalltalk in general is missing most bindings, so then I will use subprocess communication like in "good" old days...

I know how to call a command and to get its output:

```
out := LibC resultOfCommand: 'dir ', aDir.
```

but I am talking about another scenario: a communication with a running process interactively (for example, with SSH or similar like in the example above - python.exe).

PS. Maybe it's possible to do it with LibC `#pipe:mode` even?

Comment: Did you try reading my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363155/is-it-possible-to-write-shell-command-within-pharo-smalltalk/51375906#51375906? There you have stdin, pipe, etc. Does that help?

Comment: `waitForCommand` works, but it's irrelevant. In the `userInput := OSProcess thisOSProcess stdIn....` example I dont see any command line. `PipeableOsProcess` does not work. It freezes even Pharo (Windows terminal is opening, then Pharo freezes).

Comment: you do know that there's a Pharo mailing list, don't you?

Comment: oh, really! There is a mailing list... I am a very newbie, so I still did not join it, thanks for reminding, maybe it will be better to ask ST questions there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with that the `PipeableOsProcess` is probably broken on Windows.  I have tried it and it just opened a command line and nothing else (it does not freeze my Pharo 8).  The whole `OSProcess` does not work correctly in my eyes.

So I took a shot at `LibC` which is supposed to not work with Windows.

> I’m a module defining access to standard LibC. I’m available under Linux and OSX, but not under Windows for obvious reasons :)

Next is to say that Python's Windows support is probably much better than Pharo's.

The solution, which is more like a workaround using files, is to use `LibC` and `#runCommand:` (I tried to come up with a similar example as you had shown above):

```
| count command result outputFile errorFile  |

count := 9+1.  "The counting"
command := 'echo ', count asString. "command run at the command line"

outputFile := 'output'. "a file into which the output is redirected"
errorFile := 'error'. "a file where the error output is redirected "

result := LibC runCommand: command, "run the command "
    ' >', outputFile, "redirect the output to output file"
    ' 2>', errorFile.

"reading back the value from output file"
outputFile asFileReference contents lines.
"reading back the value from the error file - which is empty in this case" 
errorFile asFileReference contents lines.
```

Comment: local vars are out of the Markdown code block

Comment: @RandomB thank you for the warning, I have fixed that.